# Why can my SHA256 be different than online tools?

Tags: r, hash, openssl

Im trying to encrypt lines from a csv file with both digest and `openssl`.

```
library(digest)
library(openssl)

my_mails <- read.table("my_mails.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
my_mails$V1 = as.character(my_mails$V1)

my_mails$sha256_1 <- sapply(my_mails$V1, digest, algo="sha256", serialize=F)
my_mails$sha256_ssl <- sha256(my_mails$V1)
```

Specifically, as an example, running above with string

> %&3*,19531006@$#)?¿

Yields in R

```
a02d0c3b070e79a78eb4b2fc87ba5e96137f9bb704095a85bc8ba8617cb5b57c
```

[image]

Yields in [Here](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/sha256.php)

```
ffb7b8082b811876ea78c25fef6ac8503c53c28cc806e99ac3c8a47cea5debfe
```

[image]

what could i be missing? who should i follow?

Comment: Are they all using the same encoding and process? Why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: im reading the dataset with UTF-8, is that correct to do?

Comment: Probably yes but not sure if the site and `sha256` use the same procedure to generate the hash values.

Comment: should  SHA256 always yield the same result based on same input?

Comment: Yes, same input, same function.

Comment: Read this: Probably will help you in figuring out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700453/sha256-different-values-for-same-string

Comment: You seem to be missing the last for characters from your input: `echo -n '%&3*,19531006@$' | sha256sum` results in `a02d0c3b070e79a78eb4b2fc87ba5e96137f9bb704095a85bc8ba8617cb5b57c`

Comment: thanks for picking up that. i was incorrectly reading the csv file due to encoding. its fixed now